# SoapUI, Maven, Surefire and Jenkins Integration

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run SoapUI xml project file using maven, surefire and jenkins.
All is well for maven and jenkins, after build complete, Junit report displayed in jenkins (with very basic information - testcase name and status)

I would like to use surefire to display report and the log (i could see in target/surfire-report/ all *.xml and *.txt for the log file).
How to configure jenkins to display surefire report and log file?

here is my pom.xml file

```
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${basedir}/src/test/java/Test-API-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports/</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>soapUI</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                    <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.0</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you got this fixed, but this is how I did it.

In Jenkins for your project build **add Post-build action** of Publish junit test report result.
Set **Test report XMLs** to point to your target/surefire-reports directory where you saw the reports being written.
In the example below I'm running tests in a child module "dev" which exists in the config directory.
You'll know when it is correct because if Jenkins can't find the report xmls it will display a red error message and nothing when it has found the report xmls where you've told them they will be.

Hope this helps.

[image]